# DependencyProperty of collection type in Behavior<T>

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I am creating a behavior where I need to allow setting a list of some types to a dependency property. To be clear, here is an example:

```
<SomeUserControl .....>
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <local:CustomBehavior PropertyA="False">
      <local:CustomBehavior.PropertyBList>
        <x:Type Type="local:TypeA" />
        <x:Type Type="local:TypeB" />
        <x:Type Type="local:TypeC" />
      </local:CustomBehavior.PropertyBList>
    </local:CustomBehavior>
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</SomeUserControl>
```

As you can see, behavior needs to accept a list of types passed in XAML. The only way that I found to pass a collection of types to a `DependencyProperty` is to use a `DependencyPropertyKey`:

```
private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey PropertyBListPropertyKey =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("PropertyBList", typeof(List<Type>), typeof(CustomBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(new List<Type>()));

public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyBListProperty = PropertyBListPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

public List<Type> PropertyBList
{
    get { return (List<Type>)GetValue(PropertyBListProperty); }
}
```

However, the problem with this approach is that collection is never reset. For example, if I have two `UserControls` that use `CustomBehavior`, `PropertyBList` collection will contain types added on both usercontrols, which means that `PropertyBList` is acting like a static collection shared between all usercontrols that use this behavior.

How to solve this problem? How to have a dependency property of `List<Type>` that will be usercontrol instance specific, not shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you initialize the `PropertyBList` value by a default value in property metadata, which is shared by all instances of CustomBehavior. You could instead initialize the value in a CustomBehavior constructor:

```
private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey PropertyBListPropertyKey =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
        "PropertyBList", typeof(List<Type>), typeof(CustomBehavior), null);

public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyBListProperty =
    PropertyBListPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

public List<Type> PropertyBList
{
    get { return (List<Type>)GetValue(PropertyBListProperty); }
}

public CustomBehavior()
{
    SetValue(PropertyBListPropertyKey, new List<Type>());
}
```